# Raven.Client.MonoForAndroid.dll is not found

Tags: android, ravendb

In a previous post on Hibernating Rhinos there was told that a Raven-client for android development was available for download. Someone who knows were it could be find?

http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12929/new-client-coming-to-ravendb-mono-for-android

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2n5fioobv3v09u/Raven.Client.MonoForAndroid.dll